# TextAppearanceSpan with style from the theme

Tags: android, spannablestring

**TL;DR How can I use a style from the current theme with [TextAppearanceSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan)?**

---

Let's say I am using a custom style for my app, with a custom style for Subtitle1, like this:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/MyStyle.TextAppearanceSubtitle1</item>
</style>
```

where my theme is no more than

```
<style name="MyStyle.TextAppearanceSubtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to build a SpannedString with this custom style, so I'm using a `TextAppearanceSpan`

```
val apperSpan = TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.attr.TextAppearanceSubtitle1)
println("Your style has textSize = ${apperSpan.textSize}")
```

But in this case the output is `Your style has textSize = -1`. However, if I swap `R.attr.textAppearanceHeadline4` with `R.style.MyStyle_TextAppearanceSubtitle1`, the textSize will be right, but this isn't theme independent.

How could I extract a **TextAppearanceSpan** with a style from the current theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to pass style/appearance **resource id** to the `TextAppearanceSpan` constructor, not attribute id. To resolve attribute value from the current theme use [Theme#resolveAttribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme#resolveAttribute(int,%20android.util.TypedValue,%20boolean)) method:

```
val outValue = TypedValue()
context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.TextAppearanceSubtitle1, outValue, true)
val appearance = outValue.resourceId
//...
val apperSpan = TextAppearanceSpan(context, appearance)
```

or

```
val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(R.attr.TextAppearanceSubtitle1))
val appearance = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0)
typedArray.recycle()
//...
val apperSpan = TextAppearanceSpan(this, appearance)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I thought I could do it in only line, but it seems I was wrong.